# How can I make Flex Busy Indicator load early?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm building a mobile app with Flash Builder 4.6 and AIR.

My Main.mxml class -- a ViewNavigatorApplication -- references a splash screen set to a minimum time of 6 seconds. After the splashscreen disappears, there's a period of a couple of seconds during which the content area of the screen is just blank white -- and that's when I need the Busy Indicator to appear.

EDIT: Additional Code, as requested:

In the Main.mxml class:

```
 protected function viewnavigatorAppInitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
 {
    //checks various criteria to determine which data to load, ie which service call 
    // to make. When that is determined, code calls setUpModel().
 }

 private function setUpModel():void {   
    Model.Instance.initialize(); //adds listeners in the model, 
    //makes service call. Data is returned and parsed in the event handler.
    //APPLICATION_MODEL_LOADED event is then dispatched, and handled here

    Model.Instance.addEventListener( Model.APPLICATION_MODEL_LOADED, modelReadyHandler );
        }

        private function modelReadyHandler(e:Event):void
        {       
            //Busy Indicator only appears *after* the HomeListView is loaded.
            //I need it to appear *while* these calls are being made.
            navigator.pushView(HomeListView); //this is my First View
        }
```

So I think the question is: what is it that is being displayed before HomeListView? If it's Main.mxml -- the ViewNavigatorApplication -- then how do I avoid the 'not assignable' error?

In HomeListView:

```
        [Bindable] private var categoryList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        private function viewActivateHandler():void
        {
            //the service call has been made, and data is ready to be loaded into the control
            categories = Model.Instance.Categories;
```

I've tried this inside HomeListView:

```
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
<s:BusyIndicator 
    id="busy"
    visible="true" symbolColor="blue"
    horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
    rotationInterval="100" />
</s:Group>
```

It works. But the problem is it only appears once HomeListView has loaded. I thought that the blank white **was** HomeListView, just before the list appeared. But it isn't.

So then I tried putting the above code into the Main.mxml file.  But I got the following error:

```
 'spark.components.Group' is not assignable to the default property, 'navigationStack', of type 'spark.components.supportClasses.NavigationStack'.
```

So where can I put this BusyIndicator so that it covers the blank space before HomeListView appears?

Comment: Can you post some more of the code for HomeListView? When you say the busy indicator only shows up once homeListView has loaded, do you mean it only shows up once the service call is complete?

Comment: You can use CursorManager.setBusyCursor() and  CursorManager.removeBusyCursor() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/CursorManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way to do this.

From the [documentation](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/ViewNavigatorApplication.html):

"Unlike Application, ViewNavigatorApplication is not meant to accept UIComponent objects as children. Instead, all visual components should be children of the views managed by the application."

That is why I was getting the error. So for my first View, I created a simple View called HolderView which contains the BusyIndicator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HolderView">
<s:Group  width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:BusyIndicator 
        id="busy"
        visible="true" symbolColor="blue"
        horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
        rotationInterval="100" />
</s:Group>
```

Then, from my Main.mxml file, I first load that HolderView.

```
        private function setUpModel():void {    
            Model.Instance.initialize();
            navigator.pushView(HolderView);
            Model.Instance.addEventListener(Model.APPLICATION_MODEL_LOADED, modelReadyHandler );
        }
```

Once the data has come back -- on the Model.APPLICATION_MODEL_LOADED event listener -- that is when I will load HomeListView:

```
        private function modelReadyHandler(e:Event):void
        {       
            navigator.pushView(HomeListView);
        }
```

This works. Hope it helps someone with same problem!